# Getting Error Can't resolve 'routes/Routes in src folder of React App

Tags: reactjs

//index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

import { BrowserRouter,Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Routes from "routes/Routes";
import print from 'print-js';
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";
```

m getting the error as

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'routes/Routes' in src folder

Answer (score 0):

if those are your own files, you should reference them "relatively", like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

import { BrowserRouter,Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Routes from "./routes/Routes";
import print from 'print-js';
import indexRoutes from "./routes/index.jsx";
```

that's assuming the routes folder is in the same parent folder as your index.js file.